# Ajax request after link click with parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on Ajax. What i want to do is call a function with parameter after link click and post it through Ajax request. Here is my code:

```
<a onclick="getCategory(4)";>abc</a>
<script>
   function getCategory(cat_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            var data = {cat_id : cat_id},
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>';
        });
    }
</script>
```

Of course it doesnt work. Someone can explain where im wrong and how my ajax request works.

Comment: `data: {cat_id : cat_id};`

Comment: when i click on the link, nothing happens

Comment: `onclick = "getCategory(4)"`

Comment: Oh it was just typing. I did it correct in my code.

Comment: working now or not?

Comment: its still not working

Comment: change `var data = {cat_id : cat_id}` to `data:{cat_id : cat_id}` and check the url maybe that is the reason its not working..

Comment: It returns error getCategory is not defined

Comment: Are you sure? i tried the code and remove the ajax and the function getCategory is working.. try to put the function at the bottom part, before the end of body tag..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156407/discussion-between-tedxxxx-and-shadow-fiend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<a onclick="getCategory(4)";>abc</a>
    <script>
       function getCategory(cat_id)
        {
            $.ajax({
                var data = {cat_id : cat_id},
                type:'POST',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>';
            });
        }
    </script>
```

to

```
<a onclick="getCategory(4)";>abc</a>
        <script>
           function getCategory(cat_id)
            {
                console.log(cat_id) //testing purposes.. 
                $.ajax({
                    data:{cat_id : cat_id},
                    type:'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>';
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked in network console. It redirected but because i do nothing in the controller so. Problem solved.

Comment: @Tedxxxx i'm glad i was able to help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {cat_id : cat_id},
    type:'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>'
});
```

Comment: I changed it. But still not redirecting.

Comment: what the output of `<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You got error here:

```
$.ajax({
           //  here var data = 
            var data = {cat_id : cat_id},                   

            //  here ;
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>';
```

It was supposed to be

```
 $.ajax({
          data : {cat_id : cat_id},

          url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>'
```

You can correct like below:

```
function getCategory(cat_id) {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      cat_id: cat_id
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/category')?>',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I edited. It returns no error but still not redirecting to my controller admin/category.